# Difference between password Entropy and Min-Entrpy

Tags: cryptography, passwords, brute-force, entropy

What is the difference between passwords Entropy and Min-Entropy?

Is there a recommended number of min-entropy or standard to ensure strong passwords?

How to convert Min-Entropy to number of days/months/years?

for example: Min-Entropy of 30 bits is corresponds to computational time of 2 years in brute-force attack.

Thanks

Comment: You don't say what the computation is. More information is needed about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed about the attack that is being defended against.

The problem is not brute-forcing of the password space but rather brute-forcing a list of frequently used passwords ordered by use, say 10,000,000, that will not take 2-years. Then there is cracking hardware consisting of an array of GPUs and fuzzing software.

There is also the difference between cracking a particular password and cracking 90% of a million passwords for sale on the dark web.

What is necessary is to use an iteration key derivation function such as PBKDF2 with 100,000 iterations (about 100ms).

For more information see:

- Password list at [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).
- Infosec [password-cracking-tools](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/10-popular-password-cracking-tools/)
- Arstechnica [How I became a password cracker](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/03/how-i-became-a-password-cracker/3/)
- Advanced Password Recovery [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/)
- [DRAFT NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Authentication Guideline](
  https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html)

Comment: Thanks, Suppose that common words that users used in PWD is avoided, and final min-entropy of this single PWD is 30 bits. How to know the expected time to crack this PWD? (only one PWD)

Comment: On my laptop I can run a 20 byte password (>120 bits of entropy)  through SHA-512 and compare in under 1us so with just a SHA-512 hash I can try 1,000,000 passwords a second. 2^30 = ~10^9, 10^9 / 10^6 = ~1000 seconds. Expect a password cracking rig to be >1000 time faster.